# How to customize google search result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension with which I'd like to insert some text between the "link" and the "description" on each Google search result.  I'd like to do it with jQuery. Please, how do I go about it?

[image: google search]

Comment: please provide a code example of the HTML you wish to change and what JS code you have already tried.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple.  First we have to define URL scope in manifest.json and then include the content script that detects each search results and then appends your custom text.

Step 1: Include the content_script.js in manifest.js

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["js/content_script.js"]
    }]
}
```

Step 2: Include the below code in content_script.js

```
$("div.srg").find("h3 > a").each(function (index) {
  console.log("Title: " + this.text);
  $(this).append("<br><span style='color: orange'>My new line text</span>");
});
```

Hope it help and here is the results screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: It works thanks. But when I make another search query on the same google page, it doesn't work. Please how do I go about it.